# Decimal repetitive that can be known?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, fractions

I know that fractions 1 / 99.999.989 can produce 99.999.988 repeating digits. WOW that's a lot, I can't write that many numbers in this question. I just want to know if there are other numbers greater than that?

Comment: You're asking for prime numbers $p$ such that the [multiplicative order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_order) of $10$ modulo $p$ is equal to $p-1$. There's a lot of them. Say, $10^{80}-11=999\ldots 989$ is the biggest one below $10^{80}$.

Comment: @metamorphy That looks like an answer.

Comment: Artin's conjecture states that there are infinite many such primes (more precise, every positive integer not being a perfect square is a primitive root modulo infinite many primes).